# Can you override JavaFX font fallback at runtime?

Tags: javafx

If I specify a font for a TextField, and the text in that field has codepoints not supported by that font, JavaFX will attempt to provide a substitute font based on the fonts installed on the system.

I would like it to always appear as tall rectangles.  Why?  If the font I have specified can not be used to render the text because it lacks those codepoints, I would like to know.  Right now, I have no control over what font is actually used.

A practical example would be a simple font viewer.  After you select the font, and text is rendered with it in a preview field, you really have no idea if it is actually rendering it using that font.

Comment: Don't include "Thanks" in your questions. It's considered unneeded here.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a Font via `Font font = Font.loadFont(myFontInputStream, myFontSize);`

And set it programmatically e.g. like this

```java
public class MyFXController {

  @FXML
  TextField myTextField;

  private static Font loadFont(String resourcePath, double fontSize) {
        final URL fontURL = DefaultController.class.getResource(resourcePath);
        final Font font;
        try(final InputStream fontInputStream = fontURL.openStream()){
            font = Font.loadFont(fontInputStream, fontSize);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load font", e);
        }

        return font;
    }

  @FXML
  public void initialize() {
     Font font = loadFont("/myfont.ttf"); //font located under src/main/resources/myfont.ttf and copied to the jar under myjar.jar:/myfont.ttf
     myTextField.setFont(font);
  }

}
```

no fallbacks will be used and you will get the Tofu characters (square boxes) for unsupported codepoints.